# Global style for flyout - mahApps Metro

Tags: c#, mahapps.metro

How to create a global style for my flyouts? I have this code, but when I run it, it gives an error. Thx!

**SomeWindows.xaml**

```
<mahApps:MetroWindow.Flyouts>
    <mahApps:FlyoutsControl>
        <mahApps:Flyout Style="{StaticResource GlobalStatusFlyoutStyle}"/>
    </mahApps:FlyoutsControl>
</mahApps:MetroWindow.Flyouts>
```

**App.xaml**

```
<Style x:Key="GlobalStatusFlyoutStyle"
       TargetType="{x:Type mahApps:Flyout}">
    <Setter Property="Template"
            Value="{StaticResource GlobalStatusFlyout}" />
</Style>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="GlobalStatusFlyout"
                 TargetType="{x:Type mahApps:Flyout}">
        <DockPanel>
            //BLA BLA BLA
        </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the declaration order of the  `ControlTemplate` and the `Style`. The Style cannot acces the ControlTemplate if it's declared after it. Order is matters in XAML.

And also there could be errors in your ControlTemplate's body too.